# Valence band in silicon (semiconductors)

Tags: semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

I recently learnt that in a solid lattice there are many energy levels which are so continuous that they look like bands...
In silicon' valence band,there are those millions of 3p energy levels with 2 electrons in each..

Why dont electrons go to those empty p orbitals in the energy shell??
Like only px and py are filled in each energy level..( with 2 electrons) and there must be a z too

Those electrons can move in those $p_z$ orbital.. why dony they?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a silicon crystal with N atoms. Each atom has 4 valence orbitals. We can make 4N linear combinations, crystal orbitals, of these. The lower 2N are bonding orbitals and are doubly occupied, by the 4N electrons. Their energy range is the valence band. The upper 2N are antibonding orbitals and are empty. Their energy range is the conduction band. The lowest antibonding orbitals, at the bottom of the conduction band, are separated from the highest bonding orbitals, at the top of the valence band, by a band gap of about 1 eV.

The above is valid at T=0. At room temperature a small number of electrons is in the conduction band and the same number of holes (missing valence electrons) is in the valence band. This results in intrinsic conductivity. You can add extra electrons (holes) by replacing Si atoms by P(B). This results in doped conductivity even at T=0. Voila, the basis of the semiconductor industry.

Comment: i just got to know  conduction bands are made of antibonding orbitals.. and this makes me more confused.. i mean the way i learnt the concept was that when two atoms combine they will form 2 orbitals( one of them antibonding) .. so if N combines then N molecular orbitals... and that makes a band..Okay but if antibonding orbitals make conduction bands then only N/2 energy levles  are present in valence band  and  rest N/2 (antibonding)in  conduction band.. that contradicts what i studied